# Rebase branch on other branch in past

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I’ve got the following situation:

```
      develop
------o
       \
        \            master
---o-----o-----o-----o-----o-----o-----o
    \               /      A           B
     \             /
      o-----o-----o
```

Here, I accidentally developed feature branches `A` and `B` on top of `master` instead of `develop` (`B` branches off from `A`). In addition, `master` actually contains changes (the side-branch, and more changes to the left of my little ASCII art) which do *not* belong in `develop`, and are correct where they are.

How can I fix this repository so that `A` and `B` are rebased onto `develop`? The result should look like this (dotted branch and dotted arrow denote rebase operation):

```
      develop
------o-----o-----o-----o  <· · · ·
       \    A           B           ·
        \                             ·
---o-----o-----o-----o - - ◦ - - ◦ - - ◦
    \               /master
     \             /
      o-----o-----o
```

I *thought* that this was a simple `rebase --onto develop master A` but that resulted in the following situation instead:

```
      develop
------o-----o
       \    A
        \                 (*)
---o-----o-----o-----o-----o-----o
    \               /master      B
     \             /
      o-----o-----o
```

… where `(*)` is the old changeset `A`, and `A` is now a copy of that changeset.

I have also tried the same without `--onto`, but this resulted in an unmerged changesets which, upon inspection, turned out to  be from the repository’s very-far distant past. Skipping all these changesets then resulted in an additional, completely broken branch.

Comment: You have it correct.  After the first rebase do `git checkout B` then `git rebase --onto A HEAD~2` and you will be set.

Comment: @AndrewC Why `HEAD~2` instead of `master`? I’m assuming that’s the same here?

Comment: In your first picture you had 3 commits beyond master.  The first rebase (of A) moved the first commit.  If you use `master` for the second rebase you will try to move the same commit over again and get a merge conflict for it.  Using `HEAD~2` will take just the remaining two commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solvable by using [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). You should be able to cherry pick the commits you want from master into develop:

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick master..B
```

After this, the commits for `A` and `B` are copied to `develop`. All that remains is to rename the branches.